# How do I navigate to the album in Spotify?

Tags: spotify

When using Spotify web player (https://play.spotify.com/) how can I navigate to the album for the currently playing track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click "Open Queue app" button (below Previous Track)
2. Click the Current Track album name.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the proper way to do it. but it's the way i allways do it. Under the play/pause button, there is a list of related songs. The first song in the list should be the same song you are listening to. Click on the name of the song you are listening to in the related music category.

[image: in spofify]